# How can I dismiss a UINavigationController presented modally?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following structure:

```
UINavigationController(1) -> MainViewController     ---PRESENT MODAL---> 
UINavigationController(2) -> TutorialViewController ---PRESENT MODAL---> LoginViewController
                                                    ---PRESENT MODAL---> SignupViewController
```

I want to dismiss the UINavigationController(2) from a user action on LoginViewController.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `dissmissViewController`?

Comment: Can you provide the code for how your initializing each navigation controller, and how you are presenting the navigation and view controllers, because calling `dismissViewController` should work if implemented correctly.

Comment: You have to send `dismissViewController` to the `UINavigationController` (the second one) since `LoginViewController` is also presented modally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use delegation to dismiss the second view controller. So you would have the second nav controller be dismissed by the first nav controller, the one that presented it. This is the recommended way to dismiss modal views.

Here are the docs on [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Comment: Solved! I'm using a closure to dismiss the first navigation controller from the LoginViewController. Thanks!